# Getting Blank Page + Unable to Connect to FTP = Server Issue?

Tags: hosting, website

So my entire domain is showing a blank white page and I am unable to connect to the server via FTP. Is this most likely a server/host issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to any open ports on the server via IP or DN? If not, you could have a network connectivity problem. Or perhaps the server is physically down. I'd suggest trying to first telnet to the port of the webservice, if it works you at least rule out network.

Answer (score 0):

A blank white page suggests to me that the webserver is up but not serving any useful data.

I would start by assessing network connectivity. Is DNS returning a correct IP address? Am I reaching the intended host?

Next, I would check the status of the server. If you control the server, go in and check server logs, lists of processes, standard sysadmin stuff. Note, some people like to check the server first and then check network connectivity.

If you have a webhosting provider, you may need to call customer support.